# Ncurses no-wrap mode when adding strings to window

Tags: unicode, ncurses, curses

I'm adding strings to a window, with `waddwstr()` function, one line after other, in consecutive rows. I don't want `ncurses` to automatically wrap lines for me – I'm overwriting them with consecutive calls to `waddwstr()` and sometimes tail of previous line is left displaying. Can `ncurses` just stop when right edge of window is reached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-wrapping functions have "ch" in their name, e.g., [wadd_wchstr](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wchstr.3x.html).

The same is true of the non-wide interfaces [waddstr](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html) versus [waddchstr](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html).

However, the wrapping/non-wrapping functions differ by more than that.  They use different parameter types.  The wrapping functions rely upon the video attributes set via [**`wattr_set`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html), etc., while the non-wrapping functions combine the video-attributes with the character data:

- [`waddstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html) and [`waddchstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html) use `char*` and `chtype*` parameters, respectively
- [`waddwstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html) and [`wadd_chstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wchstr.3x.html) use `wchar_t*` and `cchar_t*` parameters.

Converting between the two forms can be a nuisance, because X/Open, etc., did not define functions for doing the conversion.

The manual page for [`bkgd`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_bkgd.3x.html#h3-bkgd) describes how these video attributes are combined with the *background character* to obtain the actual display.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer (by Mr. Dickey) is correct. However, the "ch" functions do not work with ordinary C strings (array of bytes). Another solution is to create a wrapper for `waddstr` which checks the current cursor position and window size and prints only as much as would fit.

For example:

```c
int waddstr_trunc(WINDOW *win, const char *str)
{
  int cur_x, max_x, dummy [[maybe_unused]];
  getyx(win, dummy, cur_x);
  getmaxyx(win, dummy, max_x);
  int w=max_x - cur_x;
  if (w <= 0) return 0;
  char *str2 = strndup(str, w);
  if (str2 == NULL) return 1;
  int rv = waddstr(win, str2);
  free(str2);
  return rv;
}
```