# How to print out all the strings within an array within an ncurses window?

Tags: c++, string, ncurses

I'm trying to display an array of multiple random generated strings within a ncurses window. At first, I thought this was going to be simple and I can print the array as I would with any other array: putting it through a loop and displaying each string that it comes across within the array. When I tried this, all the words were printing, just that they were coming out of the borders of the ncurses window. Then I tried to figure out a way I can set the location of the cursor for each word, but I can't figure out how I would do that. Does anybody know a solution I can keep the strings within the borders of the window? Any help would be appreciated.

```
initscr();

string wordList[19] = {"icecream", "computer", "dictionary", "algorithm", "the", "be", "to", "of", "and", "a", "your", "you", "year", "would", "work", "with", "will", "who", "which",};
string word[19];

// parameters for window
int height, width, start_y, start_x;    
height = 9;
width = 75;
start_y = 10;
start_x = 10;

//creating the window
WINDOW *win = newwin(height, width, start_y, start_x);
refresh();
box(win, 0, 0);
wrefresh(win);


// displaying random strings from the wordList array.
srand(time(0));
for(int i=0; i<19 ; i++){
    word[i] = wordList[rand() % 19];
    printf("%s", word[i].c_str());
    printf(" ");
}
wrefresh(win);
getch();
endwin();
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321517/ncurses-no-wrap-mode-when-adding-strings-to-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `printf`, use ncurses' functions like [`waddstr()`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html) instead.

Comment: Expounding on the answer, `printf` (or `std::cout`) doesn't go through the **ncurses** layer and won't honor any of the ncurses constraints, and can confuzzle the ncurses sense of what the screen looks like.  When in ncurses Rome, do as the ncurses Romans do.